# Logarithm of 3x3 matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a matrix like this.

```
A = 
30 10 40 10 50
90 20 60 50 40
30 10 40 10 50
90 20 60 50 40
30 10 40 10 50
```

and matrix p is

```
30 10 40
90 20 60
30 10 40
```

and matrix q is

```
10 40 10
20 60 50
10 40 10
```

./.. How can **i compute log of p and q?**

```
Log (p) and Log (q) ?
```

Anyone can help me .. 
I have to do this in opencv.
thanks

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#log?

Comment: why do we are about matrix A ? It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Are you looking for _matrix_ logarithm, or _element-wise_ logarithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cxyzs pointed out in the comments, there is a `log` function directly implemented in OpenCV. You can find it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#log) in the documentation.

Here is a small example of how to use it:

```
cv::Mat p, q;  // Your original matrices

cv::Mat logP, logQ;
cv::log(p, logP);
cv::log(q, logQ);

// Now logP and logQ contain the logarithms of the values in p and q
```